# Make turtles evaluate a condition based on a calculation involving a normally-distributed random variable in NetLogo

Tags: random, netlogo, distribution

I'm new to NetLogo.
My question is simple. I have a variable, let's call it ***c*** , which I need to use in a condition for turtles.
I want this variable c to distribute randomly following a normal distribution inside a range of values (in my case from 0 to +1 ) and I would like to be able to set the mean value and the standard deviation by means of two separate sliders in my interface.
So pratically speaking: Through the sliders I decide the mean and the s.d. , netlogo computes random values according to these charateristics and then these values are used in a mathematical condition, turtles evaluate the condition and only the turtles which satisfy the condition will execute a command (in my case they will just move forward and change color).
I've set the condition thanks to the people who helped my in my last question, now I need to insert this random variable c inside the condition.
I was thinking to use random-normal but apparently it only reports values, I can't use them in my condition.
Hope it was clear.

Comment: Hi jova, did that solve your problem? In case, you might consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE FOLLOWING COMMENT**

The example I provided in the first version of the answer (see below) is actually the base (which you have to adapt to your case) of what you need to do in order to have your turtles calculating a value using a normal distribution, and using the result as a condition for moving.

First of all, two important points:

1. You said "I don't need to report or print anything". Be aware that a reporter in NetLogo is not something that outputs a value to some interface When I used `print` in my example below it was a completely separate thing: only to provide a minimal but fully working example that would actively show how the computed values could be correctly used in an if-statement ("I need to use those values inside a mathematical condition". The fact that you could see the two sentences being printed in succession in the Command Center was simply a check showing that everything was going smoothly). [A reporter is instructions for computing a value, which the agent then “reports” to whoever asked it.](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#procedures) For example, `random` and `ticks` are reporters, because they give you values that you (or turtles or whoever) can use for your purposes. While `random` and `ticks` are primitive reporters, you can create your own reporters with `to-report` (just as, while `forward` is a primitive command, you can create your own commands with `to`).
2. When you need to draw numbers from a distribution, NetLogo does **not** create such distribution that is stored somewhere and from which you sample a value every time you need.
   On the contrary, every time you need a random value according to a certain distribution, you will have to generate the value using one of the [random reporters](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-reporters).

In your case, you will have the distribution's mean and standard deviation as global variables (which you will set with sliders, but for practical purposes I'm setting them here in-code since there are no sliders on SO).
Also, I understand that your turtles will have some turtles-own variable(s) that they will use in the calculation.

Good, all you need to do is to use `to-report` and write there the calculation that you want (which will include both the random value generated with `random-normal` according to the sliders, and the turtles-own variable which will be passed as input) in order to obtain `the-value`. The procedure you create with `to-report` will have to use `report` in order to actually make that value usable by agents ([see here how to use `to-report`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#to-report)).

Then, if you'll let turtles run that procedure, each of them will be able to use their very own calculated `the-value` in a condition (each turtle will execute `to-report the-value` on its own, which means that each turtle will draw a separate randomly-distributed value and will use its own `my-variable` value when performing the calculation).

As below

```
globals [
 mn             ; In the actual project, use a slider to set this.
 std            ; In the actual project, use a slider to set this.
]

turtles-own [
 my-variable    ; This represents the turtles-own variable that you want to use in the calculation.
]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  set mn 0.5
  set std 0.2
  
  create-turtles 10 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set my-variable (random 100)
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if  (the-value > 600) [ forward 10 ]
  ]
end

to-report the-value
  report (random-normal mn std + ln my-variable + my-variable + random-float 1000)
end
```

Note: I arbitrarily put 600 in the if-statement simply because, with the current example, it is a value that sometimes lets the condition be fulfilled, and some other times doesn't - which means that you'll be able to visually check that sometimes turtles move, and some other times they don't.

---

---

**FIRST VERSION OF THE ANSWER**

`random-normal` is in fact the right thing to use.
As you said, `random-normal` only reports a value; so you can just use that value in your condition.

Here are two examples of how to do it.
The two examples are equivalent in practice (as I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67939191/when-is-it-best-to-use-to-report-in-netlogo)), so up to you to adopt the style you prefer.

```
globals [
  mn
  std
]

to setup
  set mn 0.5
  set std 0.2
end

to test
  ifelse (random-normal mn std < 0.5)
    [print "it's less than 0.5"]
    [print "it's at least 0.5"]
end
```

Or

```
globals [
  mn
  std
]

to setup
  set mn 0.5
  set std 0.2
end

to test
  ifelse (the-value < 0.5)
    [print "it's less than 0.5"]
    [print "it's at least 0.5"]
end

to-report the-value
  report random-normal mn std
end
```

In any case, basically just see `(random-normal mean standard-deviation)` as any other variable storing a number.

Comment: Hey Matteo! (are you italian ? I am too!) 
Thanks for your answer but it does not help me. I don't need to report or print anything I need to use those values inside a mathematical condition. What I need is to have the possibility to set the mn and the sd trough a slider, then netlogo will create a normal distribution according to the mn and the sd i've chosen and randomly use those values in an equation. 
Like: turtles with  c * ln x + x + random-float 1000  > 1 
fd 10. I hope now is a little bit clearer

Comment: @jova95 I updated my answer: the substance doesn't change, but now it is more similar to your case + I added extra explanations. PS: yes, in fact I'm Italian -

Comment: For historical reasons, NetLogo uses the word “report” where most programming languages would simply say "return".